# CMake setup advice for complicated build process (including externalProject)

Tags: cmake

I have an application with a mildly complicated build process, and as a bit of a newb to CMake, I was wondering if anyone could provide me with any pointers.

At preset, the application consists of a single executable, built from a source tree provided in the src and include folders.

It requires a few libraries to work, the big ones being Boost and Python. Python is embedded in the application, and Boost requires knowledge of the custom python install at compile time. I also use Qt, but I'm just linking against the system Qt for this.

What I'd like to have at the end is a stage folder, containing the compiled executable, and a lib folder with the required boost and python libraries.

At present, I have a single CMakeLists.txt file, and I am using ExternalProject to build Boost and Python from bzipped tarballs of their source. It gets a little messy where I copy out the compiled libs from the prefixed install directories.

Things are working, but I have a feeling I'm doing things very backwards. I sometimes see multiple CMakeLists in nested subdirectories but don't know how they would relate to my project. Would anyone who has worked on similarly scoped projects be able to weigh in and give me some pointers?

I should add that I hope to include Windows as a platform in the near future, and that things are currently running on Linux.

Note: This is my current CMakeLists.txt, I realise that boost isn't configured and that things aren't fully moved to the stage folder. I have been doing this manually, but I wanted to ask before I dig myself much deeper :)

Thanks!

CmakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(PROJ_NAME "mwave")
project(${PROJ_NAME})

include_directories("include")
include(ExternalProject)

# Add cmake dir to cmake module path so custom find modules will work
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake  ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

#Build Python via External Project
ExternalProject_Add(
    Python
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2
    URL_MD5 2dbff60afed2b5f66adf6f77dac9e139
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure -q --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python --enable-shared
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
)

# Manually copy the compiled python files and dirs to our stage folder
add_custom_command(TARGET Python PRE_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python/lib/pkgconfig
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stage/lib/pkgconfig)

add_custom_command(TARGET Python PRE_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python/lib/python3.3
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stage/lib/python3.3)

add_custom_command(TARGET Python PRE_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python/lib/libpython3.so
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stage/lib/libpython3.so)

add_custom_command(TARGET Python PRE_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python/lib/libpython3.3m.so.1.0
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stage/lib/libpython3.3m.so.1.0)

add_custom_command(TARGET Python PRE_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink
                    libpython3.3m.so.1.0
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stage/lib/libpython3.3m.so)



#Python 
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python/include/python3.3m")
set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/python/lib/libpython3.3m.so" "pthread" "m" "util" "readline")


#Build boost via External Project
ExternalProject_Add(
    Boost
    DEPENDS Python
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/boost
    URL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/boost_1_51_0_mwave.tar.bz2
    URL_MD5 fe203a243e451b4dd4754c7b283b1db9
    UPDATE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python,system,thread,program_options
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ./b2
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
#Boost (workaround until external project is working)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "/opt/mwave/include")
set(Boost_LIBRARIES "/opt/mwave/lib/libboost_python3.so" "/opt/mwave/lib/libboost_program_options.so")


#OpenImageIO
set(OIIO_PATH "/opt/mwave/oiio/dist/linux64.debug")
find_package(OIIO REQUIRED)

#Qt4
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

#OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

# Mwave app
set(HEADERS
        "include/Application.h"
        "include/ImageChannel.h"
        "include/CompDag.h"
        "include/Dag.h"
        "include/Gui/DagView.h"
        "include/Gui/DagScene.h"
        "include/Gui/MainWindow.h"
        "include/Gui/GLViewer.h"
        "include/Gui/Nodes/GNodeEdge.h"
        "include/Gui/Nodes/GNodeLabel.h"
        "include/Gui/Nodes/GNodeCacheStatus.h"
        "include/Gui/Nodes/GNode.h"
        "include/Gui/Nodes/GRead.h"
        "include/Gui/Nodes/GViewer.h"
        "include/MwaveException.h"
        "include/Nodes/Node.h"
        "include/Nodes/Read.h"
        "include/Nodes/Viewer.h"
        "include/mwave.h"
        "include/main.h"
        "include/shaders.h"
)

set(QOBJECT_HEADERS
        "include/Gui/QCompDag.h"
        "include/Gui/QPythonEditor.h"
        "include/Gui/ViewerWidget.h"
)

set(SOURCES
        "src/Application.cpp"
        "src/CompDag.cpp"
        "src/main.cpp"
        "src/mwave.cpp"
        "src/Dag.cpp"
        "src/Gui/DagView.cpp"
        "src/Gui/DagScene.cpp"
        "src/Gui/MainWindow.cpp"
        "src/Gui/QPythonEditor.cpp"
        "src/Gui/GLViewer.cpp"
        "src/Gui/ViewerWidget.cpp"
        "src/Gui/Nodes/GNode.cpp"
        "src/Gui/Nodes/GNodeEdge.cpp"
        "src/Gui/QCompDag.cpp"
        "src/Nodes/Node.cpp"
        "src/Nodes/Read.cpp"
        "src/Nodes/Viewer.cpp"
)

QT4_WRAP_CPP(HEADERS_MOC ${QOBJECT_HEADERS})

## Compiler flags
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2")        ## Optimize
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3")        ## Optimize More
endif()

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_PATH}
                    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${OIIO_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_executable(mwave WIN32 ${HEADERS} ${HEADERS_MOC} ${SOURCES})
set_target_properties(mwave PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME mwave.bin)

target_link_libraries(  mwave
                        ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
                        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                        ${OIIO_LIBRARIES}
                        ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
                        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
                        ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

cmake 2.6, which you are using, does not support ExternalProjects.

ExternalProjects are supported in cmake 2.8 series. Please move to cmake 2.8.

The below link clarifies

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-June/044993.html